# Group rows but choose to show value of one field in group?

Tags: t-sql

I have a request which I am not certain I can grant. The desire is to group rows by certain fields but then also show an Item Description field that would break up the group and I cannot guarantee that using min() or max() on the Item Description field would result in showing the desired description in all cases.

Note in this code I have Item Description commented out, and this gives the number of rows and grouping they desire.

```
SELECT 
    --L.ITEMDESC,
    SUM(L.UNITPRCE) AS Rate,
    SUM(L.XTNDPRCE) AS Price,
    L.QUANTITY AS Quantity,
    RTRIM(L.UOFM) AS UOFM, 
    C.COMMENT_1, 
    C.COMMENT_2, 
    C.COMMENT_3
FROM 
    SOP10200 L, SOP10202 C
WHERE 
    L.SOPNUMBE = C.SOPNUMBE
    AND L.SOPTYPE = C.SOPTYPE
    AND L.LNITMSEQ = C.LNITMSEQ
    AND L.SOPNUMBE = '00644680'
GROUP BY 
    C.COMMENT_1, C.COMMENT_2, C.COMMENT_3, L.QUANTITY, L.UOFM--, L.ITEMDESC
```

Results for example transaction:

```
Rate    Price   Quantity    UOFM    COMMENT 1               COMMENT 2   COMMENT 3
0.37891 63.56   167.72421   THERMS  CESeq: 52593^Act^TARGET 10/13/2015  10/31/2015
0.34254 30.23   88.27579    THERMS  CESeq: 52593^Act^TARGET 11/1/2015   11/10/2015
```

If I include the Item Description for explanatory purposes, this results:

```
ITEMDESC                Rate    Price   Quantity    UOFM    COMMENT 1               COMMENT 2   COMMENT 3
Gas on the PG&E System  0.34691 58.19   167.72421   THERMS  CESeq: 52593^Act^TARGET 10/13/2015  10/31/2015
PGE SPCC ADDER          0.03200 5.37    167.72421   THERMS  CESeq: 52593^Act^TARGET 10/13/2015  10/31/2015
Gas on the PG&E System  0.31054 27.41   88.27579    THERMS  CESeq: 52593^Act^TARGET 11/1/2015   11/10/2015
PGE SPCC ADDER          0.03200 2.82    88.27579    THERMS  CESeq: 52593^Act^TARGET 11/1/2015   11/10/2015
```

In this specific scenario with this data they have said they want to see `Gas on the PG&E System` as the description, but I cannot just use min() or max() to resolve this transaction's scenario because that may not be appropriate for others.

So this image shows in one of the tables that I may be able to use a Unit Cost not equal to zero as the rule to choose which line's description to use. But I am struggling to think how I can implement that in code. I would like to suggest that to the client. How can I leverage Unit Cost <> 0 to choose which which Item Description is displayed?

[image: Data Options?]

Comment: We can't help you if you don't know the basis for picking one or the other.

Comment: Perhaps I could have been more specific in the final question. I'll update it to specifically ask about using Unit Cost.

Comment: But you still have a problem.  You cannot be sure if there will be any Unit Cost <> 0 or more than one

Comment: Point taken. I will have to confirm with the client that the desired line's description always has a Unit Cost and the desired line to not show a description has a Unit Cost of zero. A spot checks shows this should be true, but you're right, I'm not 100% certain right now. Thank you for helping me think through this.

Answer (score 1):

here is the outline

```
select * from 
(
select a, b, c, unitcost 
     , sum(UNITPRCE) over (partition by a, b order by 1) as p1 
     , sum(XTNDPRCE) over (partition by a, b order by 1) as p2 
     , row_number()  over (partition by a, b order by unit unitcost) as rn 
) as tt 
where tt.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Paparazzi's answer is good. Another solution would be to do something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    Max(case when L.UNITPRCE <> 0 then L.ITEMDESC else null end) AS ITEMDESC,
    SUM(L.UNITPRCE) AS Rate,
    SUM(L.XTNDPRCE) AS Price,
    L.QUANTITY AS Quantity,
    RTRIM(L.UOFM) AS UOFM, 
    C.COMMENT_1, 
    C.COMMENT_2, 
    C.COMMENT_3
FROM 
    SOP10200 L, SOP10202 C
WHERE 
    L.SOPNUMBE = C.SOPNUMBE
    AND L.SOPTYPE = C.SOPTYPE
    AND L.LNITMSEQ = C.LNITMSEQ
    AND L.SOPNUMBE = '00644680'
GROUP BY 
    C.COMMENT_1, C.COMMENT_2, C.COMMENT_3, L.QUANTITY, L.UOFM
```

If only [FIRST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) was an [aggregate function instead of an analytic function](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2012/04/10/analytic-functions-they-re-not-aggregates.aspx) you could use that, but alas we are stuck with these cruddy solutions.